# Chrome Rounded Corner css?

Tags: c#, html, css, master-pages

Helo I Have a css code like this :

```
.rounded {
   border-collapse:separate;
    border:solid black 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

and I call on page container on Aspx page:

```
<div runat="server" id="placeholder_5" class="sf_cols placeholder_5">
            <div runat="server" style="border-style: groove; border-width: medium; float: left;
                width: 100%; margin: 0; background-color: #C0C0C0;" class="sf_colsOut rounded">
                <div runat="server" style="padding: 7px;" class="sf_colsIn">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="placeholder_5_widget_0" runat="server" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but when i debug the web, only Firefox shows the rounded corner, the Chrome didn't change the view,  i look over internet, and the said on chrome use :

```
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
```

is there any solutions?

Comment: try to use border-radius only,

border-radius: 20px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome seems to be working ok. http://jsfiddle.net/cjTYs/

```
.rounded {
border-collapse:separate;
border:solid black 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-khtml-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Are you still experiencing any issues?

Comment: Right now sometimes it works somestimes it didnt work... is it Chrome bug or something?